# SSIS - error while load into fact table

Tags: ssis, null, oledb

I'm trying to load some data from **OLE DB** database with related dimensions into my fact table (which have primary keys of this dimensions) using SSIS and I'm getting some error like this:

> [F_Sales [132]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB
>   error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is
>   available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0" 
>   Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".
>
> [F_Sales [132]] Error: There was an error with F_Sales.Inputs[OLE DB
>   Destination Input].Columns[Customer_ID] on F_Sales.Inputs[OLE DB
>   Destination Input].  The column status returned was: "The value
>   violated the integrity constraints for the column."

I'm a beginner in SSIS but it doesn't make sense that there is some `Customer_ID` which is `NULL` because this column is auto increment.

Does anybody know solution of that problem?

Comment: It would not make sense at all to have a surrogate key in your fact to be autoincrement. But I'm just making assumptions. You need to post the table creation. It would make sense for `customer_id` to be an autoincrement in the customer dimension, but definitely not in the fact.

Comment: Yes, in my customer dimension customer_ID is autoincrement, no in fact table. 
But I don't understand why SSIS throws an error and wan't load into fact table when in my dimension Customer, especially in column Customer_ID, are not any column with NULL value. 

Maybe I'm getting wrong or somenthing?

Comment: Well... where are you loading your fact from? You are missing some fundamental things here. Normally you load a fact from transactions that have had surrogate keys **previously** assigned from a dimension. It sounds like you are not doing this. Is this your first fact load? How are you assigning surrogate keys in your fact load? Are you using a lookup or an update statement in a staging table? Perhaps you have business keys in your staging data that don't match dimension records but that should be obvious if you do some basic troubleshooting

Comment: Take whatever source query you are running to load the table, and look for any values with a NULL in the Customer_ID field.  If that doesn't show you anything, add a conditional split right before your OLE DB Destination to route rows with NULLs to a data viewer or another table where you can examine the records and find out how the NULLs are being introduced.